# Installing phpmyadmin in another port

Tags: apache2, nginx, phpmyadmin

I have a VPS where i host different websites, not only in apache but other platforms like Ruby on Rails. To set this up, I use nginx as front-end webserver, as proxy. I have apache running in port 8080.

Now I wanted to install phpmyadmin, so I did `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` but i get nothing when I access either `http://<myserverip>/phpmyadmin` or `http://<myserverip>:80/phpmyadmin`

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the phpmyadmin port to 8080

(default) nano /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf

Since your Apache is running on that port.

Comment: How do I do that? I dont see any line where the port is set to 80

Comment: maby this one can help you http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1329607

Comment: Or you can try to install the phpmyadmin for ngnix, since that is your front-end webserver. http://www.howtoforge.com/running-phpmyadmin-on-nginx-lemp-on-debian-squeeze-ubuntu-11.04

Comment: It is not working...

Comment: what is not working Install phpmyadmin for ngnix or changing port?

Comment: Changing the port

Comment: remove phpmyadmin, and install it again. but install it for ngnix.

Comment: Silly mistake! I copied the code from that page, and was using port 81 instead of 8080. Thanks!

Comment: What if it's on lighthttp?